# Elasticsearch no result with multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mappings with Elasticsearch 7.10:

```
PUT /test
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ekezet": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "email": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ekezet"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data:

```
POST /test/_doc/1
{
    "email": "akarki@akarmi.hu",
    "name": "lufi"
}
```

Query:

```
POST /test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "query": "akarki@akarmi.hu lufi",
                    "fields": [
                        "email",
                        "name"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Both "akarki@akarmi.hu" and "lufi" exists in the same document, but no result. Why?

If the query is only "akarki@akarmi.hu" or "lufi" there is a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `and` operator signifies that all terms must be present in a single field for a document to match**

Please refer to this ES official documentation, to know more about [cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields)

`and` is executed as:

```
+(email:akarki@akarmi.hu  name:akarki@akarmi.hu)
+(email:lufi  name:lufi)
```

You need to use the operator `or` here

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "query": "akarki@akarmi.hu lufi",
          "fields": [
            "email",
            "name"
          ],
          "operator": "or"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65006888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "email": "akarki@akarmi.hu",
          "name": "lufi"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**You can even use the `minimum_should_match` parameter that will indicate here that either `akarki@akarmi.hu` or `lufi` must be present in either of the `email` or `name` fields**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "query": "akarki@akarmi.hu lufi",
          "fields": [
            "email",
            "name"
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": "50%"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

**The cross_field type can only work in term-centric mode on fields that have the same analyzer** as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#cross-field-analysis)

So, if you change your index mapping like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ekezet": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"ekezet"     <-- note this
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "ekezet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**With the above index mapping, the search query given in the question works fine.**

Comment: Yes @LayAndrás, I just updated about this in my answer, please go through my updated answer and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @LayAndrás The cross_field type can only work in term-centric mode on **fields that have the same analyzer**